# What comic is this scene between Darth Vader and C-3PO from?

Tags: star-wars, comics, episode-identification

I ran across this image on Tumblr today:

[image: three panel comic book page, showing first Anakin creating C-3P0 with his mother telling him the droid is his responsibility. Her speech bubble leaks over to the next page where we see an imperial officer ask Darth Vader what to do with the droid. In the final panel we see Vader's black-helmeted head resting against C-3PO's disembodied head.]

It depicts an in-between-scenes moment during the Bespin part of *Empire Strikes Back*, where Darth Vader laments the fate that has befallen his creation. This acknowledges the fact that Vader as Anakin Skywalker created C-3PO, which might be one of the most out-of-place revelations from *The Phantom Menace*. What comic is this from? If there's a whole comic book devoted to placing wacky prequel revelations in context of the original series, I want to read it.

Comment: `This acknowledges the fact that Vader as Anakin Skywalker created C-3PO, which might be one of the most out-of-place revelations from The Phantom Menace.` Come on, you find it hard to believe that a slave working for a junk dealer would be able to find enough random parts to build a protocol droid? I totally buy that, in addition to him finding all the parts for a pod-racer. And a place to store the racer where no one would find it and think he stole it.

Comment: @Xantex if you have ever read song of ice and fire, I could believe that slaves could gather up everything needed, especially if it is what they are working with all day.  That being said, I totally agree with you and the lack of believability that a child hid a vehicle from everyone who shouldn't have learned about it.  Although, that being said, it seams like Watto was a decent boss, maybe he knew the kid had projects and let it go as something to help his skills that would help his business.  Maybe he didn't even consider anything Anakin might of built as worth his time.

Comment: +1 for the image - awesome find.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The image is from the 10-page comic [*Thank the Maker*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thank_the_Maker!). In fact, the image you show above is what appears on the Wookieepedia page, [with an extra panel above it](http://images.wikia.com/starwars/images/b/bc/Thank_the_Maker.jpg).